# Sagging Floor Joist in House Built in 1925

Tags: flooring

My daughter is in the process of buying her first home and she paid for an inspection. The inspector found that the joists under one of the bedrooms in the center of the house that sits on a basement foundation is sagging. We both have been told this is very easily fixed however I feel like she is getting ready to buy a problem. There are one inch holes drilled along the walls of the entire basement foundation and the ENTIRE underside of the floor system was “conveniently” covered in black plastic to where the inspector could not observe the flooring of the entire house. I have been researching and feel like it’s possible that the seller is trying to cover up at least termite damage if not something worse. Does anyone have any advice regarding this type of issue or had experience in the repair of?

Comment: Holes in basement walls are likely to drain water from flooding. The plastic might be covering mold or termite damage as you suspect. These are red flags. Any house that's 100 years old is likely going to need a lot of work, unless (maybe) lots of work has recently been put in.

Comment: That black plastic is a red light for me. As for the basement wall holes, unless there's also a drain channel flowing into a sump with a pump, any water that comes into house has nowhere to drain.

Comment: What does "along the walls of the basement foundation" mean? The question isn't very clear, as we're left to guess at construction type, materials, etc. Please provide more detail and ask something more specific.

Comment: Holes in the block wall of the basement (or a crawlspace) could also be for termite control - to allow them to inject the product as close to the foundation as possible.   Termites coming up through the hollow cores & getting into the wood is very possible with older homes that were built without termite shields over the block walls & under the sill plate..

Answer (score 1):

It's not unusual to see sagging floor joists on houses that are nearly 100 years old. Sagging joists can be adjusted with jacks, then permanently supported with a wall in the basement (or knee wall in a crawl space). This sort of thing is often best done by professionals though, because if done on your own too quickly you can cause other damage, or if done without permits, it can become a liability to a future sale of the property.

Black plastic may have been added as a vapor barrier over under-floor insulation, the 1" holes may have been part of a radon remediation effort. In other words don't jump to conclusions about fraud.

Comment: I certainly would not buy it until I had a trusted professional do a thorough termite inspection.

Answer (score 1):

If a joist is sagging, then the existing joist can be raised using jacks. Once level, then an additional beam can be installed next to and secured to the existing beam to strengthen it.

The alternative is to have a joist hanger at the end of the beams.

They did a fix similar to this on This Old House
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23amU7EWy7g